# Harmonic's equations within Single Phase Full Bridge Inverter

Tags: h-bridge, inverter, harmonics

Is it possible to find the equations of certain number of harmonics (Ex : 3rd, 5th, ... 17th) in Single Phase Full Bridge Inverter theoretically, using the characteristics of the components of the circuit ? if yes, How?, i need some documentation about that.

Comment: What you're asking for is load dependent. Is the load invariant (i.e. not a microprocessor)?

Comment: Yes, of course.  The voltage harmonics are given by the chosen PWM pattern and its timing.  The current harmonics are dependent on the harmonic filter, the voltage harmonics, and also the load characteristics.

Comment: so how do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I provided a link to a textbook chapter in my answer to your previous question. This question seems to require an answer with that kind of detail, not something that can be provided here. You may be able to find detailed material online the way I found the material for which I sent the link. Use the advanced search features of Google. To find academic material search ".edu" sites. Look at the material in Wikipedia. Note that Wikipedia articles have a lot of links to other Wikipedia articles and to material outside of Wikipedia.

Th documentation that I have is in three hard-copy textbooks from 1962, 1964 and 1994. There are certainly more recent books that can be found in libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the formula for the time-domain performance of the circuit and then do a Fourier transform

theoretically possible, probably not particularly practical without computer assistance.

many just simulate the circuit in spice and then ask for a spectrum analysis.
but that won't give you a formula, just a number.

Comment: could you give me some documentation that can show how to perform the time-domain analysis, please ?

Comment: use algebra to get a formula ro current versus time (or voltage versus time)

Comment: could you give more details ? please